# Trouble getting event listener to work properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, button

So I am a javascript noob.  I'm doing an assignment for a webdesign class and we are practicing event listeners.  So I had to assign variables to 3 separate divs, place them in an array, create a function to make them display or be hidden, and use a button/click event listener to call the function to call or hide them respectively.  this is my code:

```js
var greenBox = document.getElementById("greenBox");
var redBox = document.getElementById("redBox");
var blueBox = document.getElementById("blueBox");
var showALL = document.getElementById("showAll");
var hideALL = document.getElementById("hideAll");

var boxes = [greenBox, redBox, blueBox];

function showBoxes(boxes) {
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}

function hideBoxes(boxes) {
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

showALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showBoxes(boxes);
})


// The "Hide All" button invokes the hideBoxes method
hideALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hideBoxes(boxes);
})
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="button" id="showAll" value="Show All"><br />
  <input type="button" id="hideAll" value="Hide All"><br />
</form>

<div class="box" id="greenBox" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box" id="redBox" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box" id="blueBox" style="display:none"></div>
```

So what the heck am I doing wrong?  I've checked multiple times for typos, etc. but everything looks ok to me?  It's still not working though.

Comment: `and use a button/click event listener to call the function to call or hide them respectively.` where are these?

Comment: Without giving away your assignment, I believe you are expected to add something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: This part of your code looks fine, so I guess the bug is in the actual listeners (which you didn't post)

Comment: yes I did the eventlisteners @PhillipThomas

Comment: Can we see that code?

Comment: oh, i see.  hold on

Comment: Where are the listeners?

Comment: at the bottom now.  I forgot to add that part at first @GalAbra

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the order of loading. When do you call the JS on your page?

Comment: It was the upper case L's in showAll and hideAll... lol... smh.  thanks @GalAbra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` is case-sensitive.

You have `id="showAll"` when you are searching for `document.getElementById("showALL");`.

Pick a consistent case and it should work.

```js
var greenBox = document.getElementById("greenBox");
var redBox = document.getElementById("redBox");
var blueBox = document.getElementById("blueBox");
var showALL = document.getElementById("showAll");
var hideALL = document.getElementById("hideAll");


var boxes = [greenBox, redBox, blueBox];

function showBoxes(boxes) {
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}

function hideBoxes(boxes) {
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

showALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showBoxes(boxes);
})


// The "Hide All" button invokes the hideBoxes method
hideALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hideBoxes(boxes);
})
```

```css
.box {width: 200px; height: 36px;}

#redBox {background-color: #F00;}
#greenBox {background-color: #0F0;}
#blueBox {background-color: #00F;}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="button" id="showAll" value="Show All"><br />
  <input type="button" id="hideAll" value="Hide All"><br />
</form>

<div class="box" id="greenBox" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box" id="redBox" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box" id="blueBox" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: I just realized this when someone suggested an edit.  I swear to god I looked through this a ton of times and thought they were the same.  It's working now though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your initial typo of the div ids `document.getElementById("showALL");` should be `document.getElementById("showAll");`, the divs would also not appear without a size or contents. Something like this should do:

```js
var greenBox = document.getElementById("greenBox");
var redBox = document.getElementById("redBox");
var blueBox = document.getElementById("blueBox");
var showALL = document.getElementById("showAll");
var hideALL = document.getElementById("hideAll");

var boxes = [greenBox, redBox, blueBox];

function showBoxes(boxes) {
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}

function hideBoxes(boxes) {
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

showALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showBoxes(boxes);
});

hideALL.addEventListener("click", function() {
    hideBoxes(boxes);
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="button" id="showAll" value="Show All"><br />
  <input type="button" id="hideAll" value="Hide All"><br />
</form>

<div class="box" id="greenBox" style="display:none;background-color:green;height:20px;width:20px"></div>
<div class="box" id="redBox" style="display:none;background-color:red;height:20px;width:20px"></div>
<div class="box" id="blueBox" style="display:none;background-color:blue;height:20px;width:20px"></div>
```

Comment: It's for a class and I did not write the html portion.  there's css in there too, but it is working now.  it was just the typo

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is here in your Selectors

```
var showALL = document.getElementById("showALL");
var hideALL = document.getElementById("hideALL");
```

your Element is named "showAll" and you are using "showALL". Notice the capital "L".

Answer (score 0):

As others have said your casing needs to be consistent. One thing that may help you out when debugging this sort of thing is to open up developer tools in your browser(f12 in chrome) and placing breakpoints in the javascript so you can step through and see what the values of your variables are.

Comment: yeah, someone else wrote the html, so for some reason I thought the L's were both uppercase for the id's (which I remember thinking was weird at the time).  Sometimes it's just nice to have a second set of eyes